# when setQuickDialogTableView being called in quickdialog box

Tags: iphone, xcode, quickdialog

I am working on an example codes at [here](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/blob/master/sample/LoginController.m) and my target is to customized the font and color of log in cell

These method below are setting proper delegate class to the table view

```
- (void)setQuickDialogTableView:(QuickDialogTableView *)aQuickDialogTableView {
    [super setQuickDialogTableView:aQuickDialogTableView];

    self.quickDialogTableView.backgroundView = nil;
    self.quickDialogTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.1174 saturation:0.7131 brightness:0.8618 alpha:1.0000];
    self.quickDialogTableView.bounces = NO;
    self.quickDialogTableView.styleProvider = self;

    ((QEntryElement *)[self.root elementWithKey:@"login"]).delegate = self;
}
```

**My question is** :

```
how this method being called during the running time.
I did pull the sample project and took a look inside but still have had no clues how it is being triggered at all
```

Please advice me on this issue and all comments are welcomed here

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickDialog developer here.

This method gets called when the QuickDialogController sets its `quickDialogTableView` property to the new `QuickDialogTableView` instance, in the `loadView` method:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.quickDialogTableView = [[QuickDialogTableView alloc] initWithController:self];
    self.view = self.quickDialogTableView;
}
```

In the method above, I'm using the dot notation to set the `self.quickDialogTableView` object, but this could also have been written as `[self setQuickDialogTableView:...]`. They mean the same thing.

The loadView method is called automatically by iOS when the ViewController gets presented.